# Title not showing up for UIButton

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uikit, uibutton

I have a UIButton with an image on it.  I want to also show text under the image.

Neither the title that I set in IB now the following code seem to work:

```
[listViewUIButton setTitle:@"Blah" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Either way, just the image shows... and the text is no where to be seen...

Can someone help?

Thanks
Deshawn

Comment: just for kicks, make the button really big in IB. Do you see "Blah" now somewhere on it? I don't think you can show the text _under_ the image, btw.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of setting the image of a button, set the background image. The text should display above the background image, if I'm correct. Also, make sure your button's frame is big enough to accommodate the text.

I'm not sure if you can set the background image in IB, since I don't use it. But you can set it in code after the button is created.

Comment: How do they do it in other iPhone apps where they show the text under the image then?

Comment: You can set the background image in IB. @DeShawnT: like what? Are you thinking of tab-bar buttons? Those have text below.